# How to fix single face mesh?

Tags: shaders

[image: transparent mesh]

The model in Blender shows the mesh double faced and good looking but when exported into game looks like this. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding a solidify modifier.

Comment: If this is a Z-fighting issue, you will have to delete one of the faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though you have backface culling enabled in your game engine.  Are you using blender game engine?

You can either add a solidify modifier as gandalf3 said in the comments.  Or, if this is the only direction you will be viewing the curtains from you can flip the normals on the curtains.